# How can I enable just two days in sap.m.Datepicker and disable the rest?

Tags: javascript, date, object, datepicker, sapui5

I need to disable all days of all months in the calendar except for the fifth and tenth day

The user is suposse to choose only one of those two days,

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmDVR.png)

Any Idea how to do this? rigth know I'm trying this way:

```
                            var d = new Date();
                            var dia = "05";
                            var mes = d.getMonth()+1;
                            mes = mes.toString();
                            var anio = d.getFullYear().toString();
                            var minDate = new Date(dia+'-'+mes+'-'+anio);


                            var d2 = new Date();
                            var dia2 = "10";
                            var mes2 = d2.getMonth()+1;
                            mes = mes2.toString();
                            var anio2 = d2.getFullYear().toString();
                            var maxDate = new Date(dia2+'-'+mes2+'-'+anio2);


var inputFechaPago = new sap.m.DatePicker({ 
                placeholder: " ",
                valueFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy",
                displayFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy",
                dateValue: minDate,
                minDate: minDate,
                maxDate: maxDate
                },
});
```

but is not working as expected

Comment: Why don't you use a radio button or a select with 2 values?

Comment: because this selection can be made in different months, but just the fifth day or tenth day of it

Comment: in the change event of the datepicker you could set the Value State if not day 5 oder 10 occurs:    oEvent.getSource().setValueState("None"); oEvent.getSource().setValueStateText("NoNoNo~");

Comment: yes but this would be fired when user picks any date and the idea is configure these since the very beginning so user can not pick any day different from 5 or 10

Comment: @devtester Do you also need to provide years? Or just the months and the two days?

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the wrong format.

```
var minDate = new Date(2018, 11, 24);;
```

3 numbers specify year, month, and day; per example: 24. November 2018

The solution for you is:

```
var minDate = new Date(anio + ',' + mes + ',' + dia);
```

Comment: thanks but that is not the problem, I need to enable just fifth and tenth day and disable the others per each month. That is my real issue